# Installing Oracle Apex on a server running IIS 10?

Tags: iis, oracle-apex

I have Apex 19.1 installed on a windows server running IIS 10. Apex is working fine via localhost:8080.

I would like to map my own domain to access apex and get rid of 8080 port. I created a reverse proxy like in the following screenshot

[image]

The reverse proxy works fine when I'm in http. However when I'm in https, the home page of Apex loads (workspace, username, password), but when I try to connect to a workspace, I'm getting the error : **403 Forbidden : The request cannot be processed because this resource does not support Cross Origin Sharing requests, or the request Origin is not authorized to access this resource. If ords is being reverse proxied ensure the front end server is propagating the host name, for mod_proxy ensure ProxyPreserveHost is set to On**

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my web.config file :

[image]

Has anyone an idea on how to solve that please ?

Thanks,

Cheers

Comment: It seems that CORS header is required for your backend application. What error message did you see in F12 developer tool?

Comment: @JokiesDing thanks for your comment. The error I see is : POST https://www.example.com/ords/wwv_flow.accept 403 (Forbidden). Do you know chich header should I add to my backend application please ?